# Starting/Stopping Chained GPUImage Filters (e.g. Blur)

Tags: ios, gpuimage

For a still image camera app, I can use other filters (B&W, ChromaKeyBlend) in real-time for a preview of what will be captured, but I am interested in chaining a blur filter which I can *somehow* turn on and off regularly (without affecting the other filters). For example, disregarding autofocus activity, I want the preview view to be blurred when the user has not manually tapped the screen to indicate a focus/exposure lock. Once the focus process is complete (monitored via KVO), I want to stop the blur filter. But when the user selects/taps another area, I want the preview to be blurred again until the focus process is complete.

What I have not figured out, is how to selectively inactivate one filter (a blur filter) that is chained with other filters. Is this even possible? And if so, how is that done?

Comment: Does removing the filter from the middle of the chain and re-adding it when needed not provide a smooth enough updating to the video? That's how most people have done this that I've seen.

Comment: Also thought about zeroing out the blur value (or whatever no effect is) but thought it would still be using CPU.